# Как сделать фильтр по произвольным таксономиям Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня на сайте WP есть произвольный тип записи "Подарки", для них создано несколько произвольных таксономий.
Сейчас используется плагин для фильтра, но там он реализован по принципу выпадающего списка ([посмотреть](https://dardar.ru/podarok/price/2000/profa/vodila/)). 
Как реализовать такую фильтрацию но checkbox...
Вот скрин, идеально подходящего примера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно создать шаблон с чекбоксом... Зависит от плагина что вы используете.

Answer (score 1):

Очень годным плагином для создания фасетных фильтров в виде вот таких виджетов является платный плагин FacetWP, который умеет Ajax, контроллы любого вида, интеграцию с WooCommerce и еще много других плюсов.